# How to copy text from one textbox to Label

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" id="Amount" />
<lable id="copy_Amount" > </lable> $
```

Anything written in "Amount" input , need to written in lable

Comment: What have you tried? Also there should be lots of examples if your search a bit.

Comment: Also it should be `<label>` not `<lable>`

Comment: The use of `label` is kinda pointless here since it seems unreferenced to any input.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this

```
 <script>
       document.getElementById("Amount").onkeyup = function () {
        var stringValue = document.getElementById("Amount").value;
        document.getElementById("copy_Amount").textContent = stringValue;
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: No, you definitely shant try this. Use `textContent` due to security issues with [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: both will work using **textContent** and **innerHTML**

Comment: Yes they will, but `textContent` is preferred for to that it strips HTML and only allows text.

Comment: Input **I work </label><b>as </b><i>intended</i><label>** into your textfield and see what happens by using `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Lain There is no indication given by the OP that he html would look or should look like what you describe. The question is about taking the text from the input to the label, not about `<i><b>`

Answer (score 3):

Pointing out some obvious flaws in the accepted answer. Mainly the use of `onkeyup` and `innerHTML`.

```html
<input type="text" id="Amount" />
<!-- there is no lable tag. also label is not used as label so use span instead -->
<span id="copy_Amount"></span>

<script>
  //can input text without keyup
  document.getElementById("Amount").oninput = function(){
    //no need for another lookup - use this
    let stringValue = this.value;
    
    //do not use innerHTML due to html injection
    document.getElementById("copy_Amount").textContent = stringValue
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JQuery.

```
$('#Amount').change(function() {
  $('#copy_Amount').text($('#Amount').val());
});
```

Comment: `$('#copy_Amount').val($('#Amount').val())` would have to be `$('#copy_Amount').text($('#Amount').val())`

Answer (score 0):

1. use `keyup` event
2. Correct lable tag  `label`
3. use `text()` to set label text

```js
$('#Amount').keyup(function() {
  $('#copy_Amount').text($('#Amount').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Amount" />
<label id="copy_Amount" > </label> $
```

Comment: What if I change text using mouse?

Comment: input type is text, so how can u change from mouse?

Comment: There are various ways to enter text into inputs without using a keyboard. For example: drag-and-drop, right-click-paste.

Comment: @Lain Again, OP has not stated that copy paste or drag and drop is used.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen OP did not discard it either. Where is your point?

Comment: @JavaScript What if the input is filled by a request from SignalR or websocket? We can't take into account what could happen but only about what we know. else the case would never end.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen: Why would pointing out flaws be bad? Your hypothesis of what could be or where it could be used is as good as any others.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen: I ask differently, regarding your own comment: do you know whether the OP uses the script where there is no `lable` tag/node? No, you do not, but you assume that it is written wrongly. Because it is a probable conclusion - same as `onkeyup` not being ideal in every situation. Whether it is wrong or not is up to the OP, but it surely is good to point out. Also I do not see any downvotes anywhere, which makes it totally acceptable.